# I want to specify the linux memory size using menu.lst

Tags: linux-kernel

I have a server with 128g memory,and I hope linux only use the memory space like this:

the space from offset 0 with the size 18g,the space form offset 66g with the size 16g.

so I add two parameters in /boot/grub/menu.lst:
mem=18g mem=16g@66g

but when I reboot the machine I found that the memory size is only 14g,it means that only the latter parameter works,so how can the two parameters work together?

Comment: I use the top instruction to check the memory size, is the instruction any wrong?

Comment: This question is off-topic here; it belongs on [sf]. It's also very unclear what you're asking.